# python script to open a page and click download

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open a page and click on download button. It works fine for the pages that have download element but for the pages which doesn't have that element it raises error

Code:

```
  for i in data["allurl"]:

    driver.get('{0}'.format(i))
    if(driver.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_grdFileUpload_lnkDownload_0')):
        button_element = driver.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_grdFileUpload_lnkDownload_0')
        button_element.click()
    else:
        pass
```

It should pass instead of raising the error but when I run this it says:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
>   element:
>   {"method":"id","selector":"ContentPlaceHolder1_grdFileUpload_lnkDownload_0"}

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver.find_element_by_id()` doesn't return `True` or `False` as your if-statement expects. Either change your if-statement, or use a try/except statement.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

for i in data["allurl"]:
    driver.get('{0}'.format(i))
    try:
        button_element = driver.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_grdFileUpload_lnkDownload_0')
        button_element.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException    
try:
    button_element = driver.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_grdFileUpload_lnkDownload_0')
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
else:
    button_element.click()
```

Note that even if it worked as you expected, it's inefficient because you perform search for the element twice.

EDIT: included the import statement for the exception

UPDATE: as a side note, assuming elements in `data["allurl"]` are url (i.e. strings) there is no need for string formatting. `driver.get(i)` would do. And `i` is poor choice for variable name - better use something more meaningful....

Comment: NameError: name 'NoSuchElementException' is not defined

Comment: you need to import it with `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException`. I thought this is pretty clear :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check the length count of the web element.If it is more than 0 then element available and click otherwise it will go to else condition.

```
for i in data["allurl"]:

    driver.get('{0}'.format(i))
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_grdFileUpload_lnkDownload_0'))>0:
        button_element = driver.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_grdFileUpload_lnkDownload_0')
        button_element.click()
    else:
        pass
```